# Regex or wildcard for subdirectories in an Nginx location directive

Tags: wordpress, nginx

I have developers who will be working on their local machines editing multiple Wordpress sites. I'd like to set up Nginx for them one time without the need for them to edit the config file in the future. Typically when Nginx is configured to host Wordpress, a location block such as this is included:

```
location / {
try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;
} # End location
```

In our situation, each WP site will be in its own subdirectory. So when a developer needs to view a site, they'll go to a URL in their browser such as:

```
http://localhost/site1
http://localhost/site2
http://localhost/site3
```

What we would like is for the location directive above to include the subdirectories. As it is now, it only includes the root (http://localhost) and not the subs. I think this requires a wildcard or regex of some kind, but I'm not sure.

In other words, I think I'm looking for a location block like:

```
location /all-subdirectories {
try_files $uri $uri/ /whatever-subdirectory/index.php$is_args$args;
} # End location
```

Does this make sense or am I on the wrong track?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use a *regular expression* `location` to capture the first part of the URI, for example:

```
location ~ ^(/[^/]+) {
    try_files $uri $uri/ $1/index.php?$args;
}
```

Or use a named location with one or more `rewrite` statements, for example:

```
location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ @rewrite;
}
location @rewrite {
    rewrite ^(/[^/]+) $1/index.php last;
}
```

Comment: When I add those lines to my nginx.conf, it causes the browser to download the index.php file without displaying the page. What causes that?

Comment: I guess you are using the first solution which is a regular expression location. The regular expression locations are evaluated in order, so that rule needs be be placed **below** the `location ~ \.php$` block.

Comment: Yes! I had just figured that out on my own and came here to comment when I saw your response. Thank you very much for your help.